# Move an element from left to right and from right to left

Tags: javascript

I would like to move an element right and after that move it back to left.

I tried it like this:

```
this.style.left = '50px';
this.style.right = '50px';
```

But this doesn't work.
How can I say, do the first line and when you're finished, do the second line?

Since my CSS has `transition: all 0.65s`, it would look like an animation.

I know that I can do it with CSS and jQuery but please, pure JavaScript only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see you're missing timeout:

```
var self = this; // for passing content to closure
this.style.left = '50px';
setTimeout(function(){ // Timer
    self.style.right = '50px';
}, 650);
```

Also don't forget to add `position: relative` in CSS for your element.

I hope it will help, happy coding!